# Voice XML Disable voice input

Tags: voicexml, vonage

I am trying to disable voice recognition in a block of Voice XML code. I am finding it rather difficult to pick up this syntax, converting a project from Twilio's TwiML to the VoiceXML required by Nexmo.

Here is my code. I tried changing the `<block>` element to `<field>`, this seemed to disable voice input but then my `<goto>` did not work. Also, not related to this particular problem, how can I programmatically hang up on the caller? `<disconnect/>` does not seem to work.

```
<vxml version="2.1">
    <form>
        <block>
            <property name="inputmodes" value="dtmf"/>
            <prompt>Station 1</prompt>
            <audio src="http://foo.io/file.mp3" fetchhint="prefetch" />

            <goto next="http://foo.io/next-menu"/>
        </block>
    </form>
</vxml>
```

Comment: At first, please try to remove VoiceXML's syntax error. Move property element outer block element.

Comment: Do you mean move the property tag outside of the block tag? I believe I tried this already. Is there a way to check syntax? Any tools out there?

Comment: Yes. http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/vxml.dtd says that block element cannot have property element, And form element is possible it.

Comment: The parents of a property element can be <field> <form> <initial> <menu> <record> <subdialog> <transfer> <vxml>.  So in the example above you could put this under the <vxml> or <form>.  <goto> is generally used to go to a place in the same document.  If you are going to another document it is best to use <submit>

Comment: <goto> cannot be a child of a <field> element so that is why it did not work. Its parents can be <block> <catch> <error> <filled> <help> <if> <noinput> <nomatch>.  Show the code for you <disconnect> as this may be the same issue.  If you use a good XML editor with the schema it would alleviate a lot of these errors.

Comment: If you are more familiar with C# and ASP.NET you may want to look at something like VoiceModel [http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/] which allows you to develop voice applications for VoiceXML compliant apps and Tropo without the need to understand the underling language.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple way to accept `digits` as input. But note this would also allow speech (however, will recognize that as digits).

```
<vxml version="2.1">
<form>
  <field name="myField" type="digits">
    <prompt>
      Press some digits, okay?
    </prompt>
    </field>
    <block>
      <submit next="/next.php"/>
    </block>
  </form>
</vxml>
```

From this, whatever digits are detected - either spoken, or keypresses - will be send in the query string as `myDigits` when `next.php` is requested. Use the `method` attribute of `submit` to change to a `POST`, or the `namelist` attribute to change exactly which field are sent.

But here's a simpler version using `<menu>` instead of `<form>`, where you can set a DTMF for the `<choice>`:

```
<vxml version="2.1">
  <menu>
    <prompt>
      Press one or two.
    </prompt>
    <choice next="/pick1.php" dtmf="1">one</choice>
    <choice next="/pick2.php" dtmf="2">two</choice>
  </menu>
</vxml>
```

It's worth mentioning that there's a lot more power with VXML over TwiML. While you can duplicate the single response / XML document pattern TwiML uses, with VXML you can collect multiple fields in a single document, do data validation, fetch external data when needed, and even use JavaScript in VXML.